# ffmpeg seems to dissapear once docker is uploaded to elastic beanstalk

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node backend that uses ffmpeg. I built the docker using a multi stage build, part node part ffmpeg (Dockerfile pasted later below). Once built, I access the Docker locally and see that ffmpeg is installed correctly in it. I then deploy this docker to elastic beanstalk. Oddly, once there, when accessing the docker image, ffmpeg has dissapeared. I absolutely can't figure out what is happening, why the docker isn't the same when deployed.

Here's more details :

Dockerfile

```
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg:3.3-alpine
FROM node:11

# copy ffmpeg bins from first image
COPY --from=0 / /

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 6969
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:production" ]
```

I build the docker using this command :

```
docker build -t <project-name> .
```

I access the local docker afterwards this way :

```
docker run -i -t <project-name> /bin/bash
```

When I put in "ffmpeg", [it recognizes it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCrg8.png) and if i try "whereis", it returns me /usr/local/bin.

Then I deploy it do eb using

```
eb deploy
```

This is where things get interesting

I SSH into my eb instance. Once there, I find the container ID and use

```
docker exec -it <instance-id> bash
```

to access the docker. It has all the node stuff, but ffmpeg is missing. It's not in /usr/local/bin as it was before deploying.

I even installed ffmpeg directly on eb, but this didn't help me since the node backend searches within the docker to find ffmpeg. Any pointers or red flags that you see from this are greatly appreciated, thank you

edit : the only difference in Docker versions is the one running locally is 18.09 / API 1.39 whereas the one on eb is 18.06 / API 1.38

Comment: To anyone reading this now, 2 things that I had done wrong
1) I hadn't commited my Dockerfile, so it wasn't taken into consideration
2) My elastic beanstalk t2.micro instance just didn't have enough cpu or ram to complete installing ffmpeg so it timed out.
Once these two things done, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My elastic beanstalk t2.micro instance just didn't have enough cpu or ram to complete installing ffmpeg so it was timing out. Upgrading to a t2.medium solved the issue